# Crear archivo temporal en memoria

Tags: python, python-3.x

Quisiera saber si existe una forma de hacer que se guarde un archivo en memoria sin necesidad de escribirlo en el disco. por ejemplo:

```
imagen = wx.Bitmap('imagen.png', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)
```

ahora quiero tomar los datos de la imagen y guardarlos en memoria, wx.Bitmap tiene una función para guardar la imagen:

```
imagen.SaveFile('nombre_Archivo.png',wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG)
```

Existe alguna forma de guardar la imagen en memoria sin necesidad de escribir en disco?, algo como:

```
imagen.SaveFile('espacio en memoria',wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG)
```

Comment: No te entiendo muy bien, pero la variable `imagen` es el contenido de tu archivo en memoria. Qué harias con un archivo en memoria que no pueda hacerse con la variable?

Comment: necesito pasarlo a una imagen para despues leer los bytes, con un archivo seria imagen = open('imagen.png', 'rb'), data = imagen.read()

Comment: Entiendo, no conozco nada similar a crear un archivo en memoria. En vez de eso, creo que deberias mirar cómo se formatea la imagen antes de escribirla, es decir, codificarla en jpg, png, bmp, etc. Pues el proceso es codificarla y luego los bytes resultantes, escribirlos a un archivo. Así que no necesitarias "escribir" y luego "leer" bytes sino interceptar el buffer de la imagen codificada.

Comment: El problema es que wx.Bitmap me devuelve un objeto, pensé en utilizar io.BytesIO() pero la unica forma que he conseguido que me devuelva una imagen es con a funcion SaveFile()

Comment: Cuando usas el método `SaveFile`, se convierte la imagen al formato especificado y luego escribe en disco. Debes mirar **cómo** se codifica (Estos son los bytes que necesitas) antes de escribir al archivo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sí se puede, usando el módulo [`io`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html), pero aún así no sé si servirá para lo que te propones.

El módulo `io` permite crear objetos que se comportan como si fueran ficheros y se pueden pasar como parámetros a las funciones que esperan un fichero, pero no acceden a disco sino a memoria.

Por ejemplo:

```
import io

f = io.BytesIO()
imagen.SaveFile(f, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG)

...

data = f.getvalue()
```

El problema es que `wx.Bitmap.SaveFile()` no admite un fichero como parámetro, sino un *nombre de fichero*, que no es lo mismo. Internamente abrirá ese nombre para obtener el fichero en el que volcar los bytes. Si se pudiera acceder de algun modo a esa maquinaria que vuelca los bytes pasándole el objeto `BytesIO` en lugar del fichero, el problema estaría resuelto. Habría que mirar la API y tal vez la implementación de WxPython.

### Actualización

Aunque la clase `wx.BitMap` no proporciona métodos de bajo nivel para acceder al *stream* de bytes, la clase [`wx.Image`](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.Image.html#wx-image) en cambio sí. Por tanto, lo siguiente debería en principio funcionar.

```
import io
import wx

imagen = wx.Image()
imagen.LoadFile('imagen.png')

# Tal vez procesarla...
# Y ahora guardar el resultado en memoria

f = io.BytesIO()
imagen.SaveFile(f, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG)

# Los bytes los tenemos aqui:
data = f.getvalue()

# Comprobación de que la cosa va bien
print(data[:10])
```

Lo anterior muestra:

```
b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00'
```

que en principio tiene buena pinta.

Comment: Esto es precisamente lo que necesito,pero no encuentro nada sobre como hacerlo

Comment: @Krilosax Actualizada de nuevo, corrigiendo errores. He verificado que funciona.

Comment: De todas formas,  entiendo que la imagen que guardas "en memoria" no es exactamente la misma que has leido del disco, pues de lo contrario no hacía falta pasarla a través de `ws.Image()`. Te bastaría leer directamente el PNG del disco, con algo como `with open("imagen.png". "rb") as f: data=f.read()`

Comment: Exactamente lo que necesitaba, no habia investigado sobre wx.Image(), la intension es guardar los bytes de una imagen tomada de un staticBitmap, esto me funcionó perfecto. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Me encontré con un problema parecido hace poco (lo intenté con OpenCV) y me encontré con este post. La solución que encontré es crear un archivo temporal con la funcion NamedTemporaryFile():

```
import tempfile

# Crear un archivo temporal con nombre 
archivo_temporal = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False, prefix="", suffix=".png")
```

Entonces se puede interactuar con las funciones de apertura y guardado de datos mediante el método .name:

```
nombre_archivo_temporal = archivo_temporal.name
```

En la consulta del comienzo (uso de wxWidgets) esto debería andar:

```
# ....
imagen.SaveFile(archivo_temporal.name ,wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG) # escritura en RAM
```

Yo hice la prueba con OpenCV y funcionó bien:

```
import cv2 as cv

img = cv.imread('imagen.png') #lectura desde disco
cv.imwrite(archivo_temporal.name, img) # escritura en RAM
```

La transferencia de la imagen al archivo temporal tambien se puede hacer mediante la apertura en formato binario con la función open(). También funcionó bien:

```
# # Abrir archivo en modo lectura binaria
archivo_disco = open('imagen.png', "rb")
data = archivo_disco.read()

# Asignarle la data al archivo
archivo_temporal.write( data )
archivo_temporal.seek(0)
```

Si dejamos la opción 'delete=false' al crear el archivo temporal este no se eliminará automáticamente al cerrarlo sino que deberá ser eliminado mediante comando del sistema operativo:

```
import os

os.unlink(archivo_temporal.name)
```

o en su defecto se eliminará al reiniciar el equipo. Por defecto 'delete' es True.